# Helm /.helm/repository/local/index.yaml file is empty

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a private git repo to store the company helm charts. This git repo has .tgz and index.yaml file.

I am trying to test/re-run the existing chart locally using `helm serve .`

The issue I have now is, the `helm serve` is not serving the local private helm chart.

And the index.yaml file under `~/.helm/repository/local` is empty.

```
cd ~/.helm/repository/local
 $ cat index.yaml             
apiVersion: v1
entries: {}
generated: "2019-09-29T10:38:13.526444+01:00"
```

Also `helm search local/` unable to find the chart that I am looking.

```
 $ helm search local/ 
 No results found
```

```
$ helm repo list 
NAME    URL                                         
stable  https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
local   http://127.0.0.1:8879
```

What I am expecting is `index.yaml` under `~/.helm/repository/local` should has the list of private charts. And the `helm search local/` would return the chart that I'm looking for.

Also I noticed the `helm serve` command is reseting the `index.yaml` file to empty instead of loading the private charts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve charts from a non-default directory, use `helm serve --repo-path <path>`.

This [github issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4242) might also be related. According to it, you'll have to add a separate repo for the locally served one, like `helm repo add test http://127.0.0.1:8879/`.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem after I had run a local chart repository server which points to the local folder with charts. `helm serve --repo-path ~/.helm/repository/local`. That let me run the local charts using command `helm install local/{chartName}`. `index.yaml` was regenerated after a local server running.